# Catching errors at the end of a chain of promises

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, error-handling

I am using a factory to query data from Parse.com, this occurs many times in my ionic app and would like to apply a little more DRY to my code.

To call data I am using:

```
ParseFactory.provider('Clients', query).getAll().success(function(data) {
    $localStorage.Clients = data.results;
}).error(function(response) {
    errorFactory.checkError(response);
});
```

And often run many of these back to back to get data from different classes on the loading of a page.

Is it possible to use one error block at the end of all of these? like this:

```
ParseFactory.provider('Favourites', query).getAll().success(function(data) {
    $localStorage.Favourites = data.results;
})
ParseFactory.provider('Somethings/', query).getAll().success(function(data) {
    $localStorage.Programmes = data.results;
})
ParseFactory.provider('UserItems', query).getAll().success(function(data) {
    $localStorage.UserExercises = data.results;
})
ParseFactory.provider('Customers', query).getAll().success(function(data) {
    $localStorage.Clients = data.results;
}).error(function(response) {
    errorFactory.checkError(response);
});
```

Comment: Those 4 requests are completely independant, but you want them to succeed all, or fail if any of them fails, right? If so, that's what $q.all() is for.

Comment: Yeah that's correct they should all succeed or something is wrong. So in the case of $q.all do I need to wrap additional $q.defer around each of them or will the returning promise I have now be ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create helper method:

```
function query(resource, query) {
  function querySucceeded(data) {
    $localStorage[resource] = data.results;
  }

  function queryFailed() {}

  ParseFactory.provider(resource,  query)
     .getAll()
     .success(querySucceeded)
     .error(queryFailed);
}
```

and, then just call:

```
query('Favourites', query);
query('Customers', query);
```

and so on.

Alternatively, you could factor queryFailed out, as such:

```
function query(resource, query) {
  function querySucceeded(data) {
    $localStorage[resource] = data.results;
  }

  return ParseFactory.provider(resource,  query)
     .getAll()
     .success(querySucceeded);
}

function queryFailed() {


}

$q.all([
    query('Favourites', query1),
    query('UserItems', query2)])
    .error(queryFailed);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I ask when using a variable to set the $localStorage you use [resource] on the first and then ['resource'] should this be [resource] for both? This actually answers a question I posted last night regarding setting a $localStorage key to a variable value.

Comment: Yep it should be. Fixed typos.

Answer (score 1):

$q.all takes an array (or object) of promises, and returns a single one.

The returned promise is resolved when all the original promises are resolved. It's rejected as soon as one of the original promises is rejected.

So, what you can simply do is something like

```
var request = function(path) {
    return ParseFactory.provider(path, query).getAll();
};

var promises = {
    favourites: request('Favourites'),
    programmes: request('Somethings/'),
    exercises: request('UserItems'),
    customers: request('Customers')
};
$q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    $localStorage.Favourites = results.favourites.data.results;
    // ...
}).catch(function() {
    // ...
});
```